# Rename columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, create-table

I want to (directly) generate a table with the content from 2 columns of another table. How ca I change the names of the columns (rename them in the new table)?

Here´s an example:

```
CREATE TABLE X AS
SELECT
Table1.name,
Table1.act
FROM Y
```

->I don´t want to name the columns "name" and "act" as in the original table - I want to have "name" replaced by "customer" and "act" replaced by "status"

Comment: `... Select Table1.Name As Customer, Table1.act As Status ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE X AS
SELECT
Table1.name as customer,
Table1.act as status
FROM Y
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just specify name aliases in the query:

```
CREATE TABLE X AS
SELECT
Table1.name AS customer,
Table1.act AS status
FROM Y
```

Alternatively, you could specify the column definitions in brackets after the table name:

```
CREATE TABLE X (customer VARCHAR(10), status VARCHAR(10)) AS
SELECT
Table1.name,
Table1.act
FROM Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a While Loop to do that:

```
$my_query = "SELECT * FROM tj_ethnicity FROM Table_X";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_query))
{       
    $new_query = "CREATE TABLE `."$row['customer']".` (
        `customerid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `status` varchar(50) DEFAULT ."$row['status']".,
        `created` datetime NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`customerid`)
    )";

}
```